# How to set title of push notifications in php script?

Tags: php, push-notification, android-notifications

I have to set title of push notification . I am using fcm to send push notifications . If I use setContentTitle() method to set my notification title from the app it works but if i use the following php code below at my server it doesn't work.Please help me

```
$inc_phone = $_POST["inc_phone"];

function send_notification ($tokens,$message,$title,$inc_name)
{
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $fields = array(
         'registration_ids' => $tokens,
         'data' => $message
        );
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization:key = AIzaSyAe9Qxx2URTyqXmf0mTheMq_ss_DOJaVQs ',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
   $result = curl_exec($ch);           
   if ($result === FALSE) {
       die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
   }
   curl_close($ch);
   //Decoding json from result 
    $res = json_decode($result);


    //Getting value from success 
    $flag = $res->success;

    //if success is 1 means message is sent 
    if($flag == 1){
        echo "Notification sent from ".$message['title'] ." to ".$inc_name;
    }else{
        echo 'Notification was not sent why?';
    }
}
//Connect to the database
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$user = "rajhanssingh";                     //Your Cloud 9 username
$pass = "";                                  //Remember, there is NO password by default!
$db = "fcm";                                  //Your database name you want to connect to
$port = 3306;                                //The port #. It is always 3306

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db, $port);

//$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","fcm");
$sql = " Select token From utoken where phone_no='$inc_phone' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$tokens = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $tokens[] = $row["token"];
    }
}

$q = " Select name From utoken where phone_no='$inc_phone' ";
$res_name = mysqli_query($conn,$q);
if(mysqli_num_rows($res_name) > 0 ){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_name)) {
        $name = $row["name"];
    }
}

mysqli_close($conn);
$message = array(
    'title' => $title,
    'message' => $body
);
$message_status = send_notification($tokens, $message,$title,$name);
echo $message_status;
 ?>
```

Comment: do it from the app..if you want a different title depending on the notification you could add a new variable to your php script and make app setting the tittle from this variable

Comment: But i am able to set the body using this code but title is not working I am not able to get what you are telling . I want to send notification from one user to another user and title of the notification should be the name of the user who is sending the notification.Please help me doing this. I have been working on this problem since a week. I have searched everywhere but could not find anything